# Python-Selenium does not find existing element by id

Tags: python, selenium

I have a page with the following element (I cannot share the URL as the page is private):

```
<input readonly="" type="text" class="form-control" id="submissionKey" value="{{ token }}" style="font-size:1.2em;color:black; width: 400px">
```

which I am trying to get with the following method:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("submissionKey")
```

but this only gives an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="submissionKey"]
```

I also tried to implement some wait like this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'submissionKey')))
```

which then gives an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

What am I missing here?

**Additional information**

- It does not look like a timezone problem
- There are no iframes involved.

Complete page body:

```
<body style="margin:20px">
    
    <p>Go to <b>Jupyter Notebook</b> and complete the exercise.</p>

    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon" style="width:40px;font-size:1.2em"><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <input readonly="" type="text" class="form-control" id="submissionKey" value="{{ token }}" style="font-size:1.2em;color:black; width: 400px">
        </div>
    </form>

    <p style="margin-left:55px"><small>Use this key to fetch the simulation results in the notebook in order to complete the exercise.</small></p>

    <script>
        console.log('window', window.location.search);

        var queryString = window.location.search; // Returns:'?q=123'
        let params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        let auth = params.get("auth");

        var input = document.getElementById('submissionKey');
        input.value = auth;
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: i guess its timezone problem, check it once again and tell if its not working dude

Comment: Did you check for iframe ? can you share page URL ?

Comment: no timezone issue, no iframes involved

Comment: Can you share page URL ? I suspect there would be multiple elements.

Comment: No I cannot. It is not public

Comment: Do you have some wait / delay before that command to let the element be loaded before accessing it?

Comment: do one thing share the page resource instead then

Comment: I added the COMPLETE body to my question

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I added the complete body. The exact same phrase is mentioned in a script snippet, as you can see in the question.

Comment: Do this `input` visible from the beginning on the page or you should click etc to open or change thing there in order to make this element appeared?

Comment: BTW, what is about your previous question? Was it resolved by our answers?

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about. I want to get this element from the DOM. Thats all. I do not care if it is visible, clickable, sane, insane, insecure, pandemic or infected. It is in the DOM. I want this element

Comment: By this `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'submissionKey')))` you are waiting for element matching the passed locator to be clickable. In case the element is present, but hidden etc. - not visible and not clickable, the above condition will not be fulfilled and the timeout exception will be thrown...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236197/discussion-between-alex-and-prophet).

Comment: The page I want to check has been opened in a new tab. Could that be the reason? Maybe the stupid selenium driver is still on the first tab?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, selenium is again not "following" what a user is doing. With selenium, you have to take care if you are in an `iframe` yourself (selenium only works on a single iframe, not the whole page a user sees), nor does it automatically switch when the browser opens a new tab. That was the case in this example.

Some test opened a new tab, and you have to manually switch to it. For python-selenium you can do that using

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

You can close that tab using

```
driver.close()
```